# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with apache dbcp2 in gradle

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I recently created a class which uses `BasicDataSource` from dbcp2, however when i try to use methods from this class, i get the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSorce` error even though i have the dependency added in my build.gradle: [image]

What could be causing this issue, and how could i fix it ?

Class which uses `BasicDataSource`

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseUtils {

    private static final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

    static {
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
        dataSource.setUsername("username");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }

}
```

Comment: How did you try to build the program? Console, IDE (if so, which ones?)

Comment: @M.Dudek I built it via IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) with the command `shadowJar` , as i am using the shadow jar plugin

Comment: is the Gradle build successful?

Comment: @tuhin47 Yes, the gradle builds do succeed, however when i run it (this is a minecraft plugin) and the method gets called, i get that error.

Comment: can you provide the class BasicDataSource??

Comment: Yes 1 second, i will edit the post and add the class where `BasicDataSource` is used.

Comment: what is your mysql version??

Comment: @tuhin47 my mysql version is `5.7.35`

Comment: You need to add this jar as well mysql.mysql-connector-java:5.1.46

Comment: @tuhin47 i have that added in my build.gradle `compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.46'` .  Should i get it is a jar aswell and add it?

Comment: it's ok with your Gradle. But make sure all the jar are downloaded properly. You might check them from external Libraries. https://i.imgur.com/Id6mOYZ.png. Also create your database properly

Comment: I have all of them there as far as i can tell. https://imgur.com/ATE4nYU

Comment: I checked the JAR file, the class is there, i have no clue on why it is giving this error.